# Heroku How to add 'addons' to the project if I am not owner of the project?

Tags: heroku

My client has all rights to the heroku account, he is owner, but at the same time he is not a technical person. How could I add any addons to the project using terminal? Let's say I am adding and my client is only accepting? Is it possible? Now I need to ask my client for helping me every time. He needs to find a proper addon etc... miss I something with configuration of accounts?

Comment: Your client can add you as a collaborator: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing

Comment: 'Collaborators can perform any action that an owner can, except collaborators can not: Add or remove paid add-ons'  It's not the answer to my problem. Is possible to be collaborator and to have rights for ordering addons, and owner only will click some link for accepting this?